# SharePoint List / Library property bag

Tags: 2007, development, splist, properties

I'm working with sharepoint 2007 and i have a question, does a sharepoint library / list has something like property bag, where i could store some properties for the list? Like a SPWeb object.
Or maybe not property bag, but something similar?

Or is there only SPWeb.Properties to store the properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as you can see from the msdn documentation, the SPList object does not have a "Property Bag" property.

That said, if you need to, a common workaround is using the property bag of the root folder of the list as a surrogate. You see... [SPFolder does define a property bag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties.aspx). Also you can take for granted that a (normal) list or document library should have a root folder: that means that you can store the required properties on the folder (maybe use a custom key prefix to distinguish them from the other properties) and work your solution from here.

Answer (score 1):

How about using hidden columns in the list to store your information? Should be an easy implementation and quite easy to use aswell

Answer (score 1):

You can create an element manifest property bag for a file, folder, list item, or website.

For example:

```
<PropertyBag HyperlinkBaseUrl="http://contoso.com/sites/EastEnglandSalesOffice"" Url="Lists/CurrentDiscounts" ParentType="ListItem" ItemIndex="23"/>
    <Property Name="DaysToLive" Value="90" Type="int" />
</PropertyBag>
```

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491705(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491705%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use property bag of the root web?

To identify your keys just do a prefix of the property a name of your list or its guid or something similar. E.g. youlist_myproperty1, youlist_myproperty2 etc.

To get

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Properties[key]
```

or set properties

```
SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Properties[key] = value
```

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Comment: nice to know that someone agrees -_-