# How to create an auto incrementing counter that resets every year

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

I am new to working with SharePoint list. Currently, I am tasked to create a unique Sample ID that will be created by concatenating multiple calculated fields in SharePoint list, but the catch is every year the number at the end needs to reset.

I am having trouble creating an auto incrementing field that resets every year.

Any thoughts? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example:

```
2020PI1
2020PI2
2021PI1
2021PI2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of Flow (PowerAutomate) so if you're up for it, you could:

1. Trigger flow on list item creation
2. Get list items & ID the highest value
3. Use a compose or variable to pull in the current year
4. Concat & update item

It's a little bit of parsing work, but shouldn't be a huge flow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume using Power Automate will be more handy to you. Two flows will be enough handling you task. One is to fill in the counter column with a auto increment variable. One is to reset the counter once a year.

There is type of flow called schedule flow which you can easily set it to run once a year at a certain time so this part is very easy.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks

And for the auto incremental part, here is an example for you:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Flow-PowerAutomate-How-to-auto-increment-the-data-in-sharepoint/td-p/408144

Answer (score -1):

In order to get this to work, you will need to store two numbers:

- The current value of the auto-increment number
- *What year* that auto-increment number is from (because you will need to check - if it's a new year, you need to reset the auto-increment number)

The way that I have gotten this to work most effectively is by storing those numbers as properties on the property bag of the list where I am using those custom ID numbers, and generating the custom ID (and checking those numbers stored on the property bag) using an [`ItemAdded` event receiver](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/02/event-receivers-in-sharepoint/).  (As [this answer states](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/64630/8992), technically a `SPList` object does not have a `Properties` "property bag" property, but the `SPFolder` that is the `SPList.RootFolder` does.)

What is a property bag?  It's a way we can store key/value pairs internally in SharePoint at various hierarchy levels (Web Application, Site Collection, Web, Folder, etc.), which would be perfect for storing a couple numbers we need to use in code / an internal process, which we do not necessarily want everyday users to see.

I mention all that because you have tagged your question with [sharepoint-enterprise](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-enterprise) which implies that you are working with a version of SharePoint on-prem and can therefore use server-side C# code, which all of the above relies on.

If you are comfortable programming C# server-side SharePoint code, and can deploy said custom code to your SharePoint farm, I would look into that.

However, you also state that you are new to working with SharePoint lists, and have also tagged your question with [workflow](/questions/tagged/workflow), which leads me to believe you may not be comfortable writing a custom code solution in C#.

If this is the case, there is still a way to get this to work.  Unfortunately you can't access any property bags from SharePoint workflows, so you won't be able to use the property bag on the list's root folder.  You'll need to figure out some other way of storing those two numbers that you can access and write to from a workflow.  Luckily, SharePoint gives you just such a mechanism: *lists*.

That's right, all you would need to do is create a custom list (perhaps make it hidden from the UI, so that regular users don't mess with it and accidentally edit the values), who's *only reason for existence* is to store the two numbers you need for your auto-numbering system.  I would make the Title field optional, add a column called "Year" and a column called "CurrentID", and create a single list item, and set the "Year" to be this year, and the "CurrentID" to be `0` (zero). (You'll see why in a minute.)

Then set up your workflow to do this:

- When an item is created, go to your ID numbering tracking list and get the single tracking item there (ID: 1), and get the stored values of the `Year` and `CurrentID` columns.
- Figure out the year the current item (that was just created) was created.
- **If the created year is the same as the stored year**, increment the the `CurrentID` by one and save that in a workflow variable (see - if we initially set that to 0, after incrementing on the first created item we end up with 1).
- Save that new `CurrentID` from the workflow variable back to the tracking list.
- Use the `Year` and the new incremented `CurrentID` workflow variable along with whatever other data you need from the current item to generate your custom ID, and set it on the current item.
- **If the created year is not the same as the stored year**, increment the `Year` value, and set the workflow variable that would have been an incremented `CurrentID` to be `1`.
- Save *both* of those changed values back to the tracking list.
- Use the incremented year, the new `CurrentID` value of `1`, and whatever other data you need from the current item to generate your custom ID, and set it on the current item.

So all you need is a list with a single item that will keep getting updated with the "current year" (which will only change once per year) and the "current ID" (which will get updated with every new ID generated), and you can have an auto-incrementing number that resets on each new year.

Comment: You don't need to store the year - you can get that from `Today()`. You don't need to store the current ID, either - you can lookup the last one, for the current year, from the last item on the list, itself. If there are no items for the current year, ID = 1 (and do the prepending of the year and "PI" for proper syntax). This is more complicated than it needs to be and doesn't give the formulas needed for setting this up.

Comment: @vapcguy What happens when the last item in the list gets accidentally deleted (let's say it was 2023PI34), then a new item is created and looks up what is at that point the last item (now 2023PI33), increments one to assign the new item 2023PI34, and then the item that was accidentally deleted gets restored?  Now you have 2 items with the same ID of 2023PI34. You can't guarantee uniqueness that way, which is why you need to store the current incrementing ID somewhere and refer to that when assigning new IDs.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the last one gets deleted because you're only setting this value when you're saving the item as a new item the first time. It won't ever change after that. But even in your scenario of restoring a deleted item-because it's a text field-the admin doing the recovery will know to just increment the value manually-based on the current last value on the list-or they can just manually update the one that was originally auto-assigned the 2023PI34 to whatever the current ID is at the time, instead. The last ID is always the last item on the list-whatever it happens to be at the time.

Comment: First of all: "the admin doing the recovery will know to just increment the value manually". Will they, though? That's a huge assumption to make. What if the admin who was there when the system was built knows that, but after 4 years, they're gone and there's a new admin who doesn't know the implementation details of that particular list because they are responsible for 30+ site collections across 5 web applications? And it does matter if the last one is deleted, both in the case of accidental deletion or purposeful deletion. If it was accidental, what if the last item got deleted on...

Comment: ...a Monday, and it was a busy week and 100 new items got added before someone realized they had to restore the item. Now the admin who supposedly "knows" they have to edit the IDs has to go through and re-increment the IDs of all 100 new items to keep them in order after re-inserting the recovered item. Unecessary work. And in the case of purposeful deletion - what if there are other lists that reference the IDs, and by deleting an item, it should invalidate any reference relationships? If the last item gets deleted, but a new item is created and gets dynamically assigned the same ID, then...

Comment: ...any items elsewhere referring to the ID of the item that got deleted, which should now correctly have invalid references, now refer to the new item (incorrectly) because it was assigned a duplicate ID.  There are so, so many things that can go wrong if you are assigning "unique" IDs based on dynamically looking up whatever the last item in the list is at the time a new item is created.  I mean - why do you think it is that SharePoint's own internal list item IDs behave the way they do?

Comment: You're off the rails! The admin's the one overseeing SP! So YES, they're going to know to update the custom ID! Guess you never heard of transitioning your projects before you leave. Even if they didn't, those using the list will know when they have duplicate IDs because they're the stakeholders tracking them and asked for this special ID in the 1st place! If you really wanted an automated safeguard, you can build it into the form: `If (SharePointForm1.Mode = FormMode.Edit, ... )` in the Default property of the textbox of the custom ID field, add getting the last ID & increment if it's a dupe.

Comment: You can check if it's a dupe w/something like: `If CountRows(Lookup("My List", ThisItem.CustomID = CustomID).CustomID) > 1`. Whether it's an accidental/purposeful deletion makes no diff-still a deletion! Doesn't matter if 1 or 1000 items get created before the ID is updated, you'd still just either manually or auto-increment the custom ID of the restored item based on the last available ID. No other updating to any other item is necessary, don't be so melodramatic. You wouldn't want to change those items that got IDs, anyway, for the very reasons you mentioned-having other things tied to them.

Comment: And any admin restoring a deleted item is going to know relationships can break & would be looking at the restored item to ensure its values all came back ok. But that's a completely diff issue & has 0 to do w/a custom ID field-other lookup lists aren't going use it-they have their own built-in ID & are conn to whatever lookup column that's built on that list-not the custom ID. If the last item is deleted & a new one created & it gets the custom ID of the deleted one, so what? It's 1 item that got replaced w/another & they can tell anyone who's looking for the deleted one not to worry about it

Comment: But often, people will start an item, delete it, then want to re-create it. This way they can do that & get the same ID without having to call up the admin to restore it. If people care that much about there being a gap when an item is deleted, how is your "ID numbering tracking list" going to solve that, anyway? If an item gets deleted, you'd leave it on this list? Then you're tracking defunct IDs, not just used ones. Both ways have their advantages, but to act like how I was describing to do it is somehow ridiculous is insane.

Comment: And saving "both of those changed values back to the tracking list" in your 2nd case is just messy & you can't tell which ID was used, then.

Comment: How so? You know exactly which ID was used because what's in the tracking list represents the last ID used. In the 2nd case, that's the new, updated year, and "1", because it's the first item created in the new year when the year value increments. In the workflow, you both set the ID of the item to that and reset the tracking list to the new year and reset the incrementing part to 1. 

Anyway - enough already. You think my approach is bad, fair enough, I think your approach is bad.  We can agree to disagree.

Comment: If an item is saved in the tracking list, deleted, & a new one is created & ALSO logged, you still didn't say how your system knows which is which. What you said about incrementing the yr, giving it a "1" for the 1st item of the yr only works for the item being created as the 1st item of the yr. But that part was all fine, anyway-whether the form or workflow does it, toh-MAY-to, toh-MAH-to-but a flow can cause issues if updating an item with a flow already on it that runs if updated. Was more concerned about the usefulness of the tracking list & was thinking it redundant to the built-in ID.